# How to Set A Label's Text to a data in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to set Data from Firebase into a Label?
I tried it but it didn't work:

```
databaseRef.child("ServiceA/Title").setValue(InputA.text)

LabelTest.text = databaseRef.child("ServiceA/Title").value(forKey: "TitleA") as? String
```

[image: Fi]

but i get the error:

> Thread 1: Exception: "[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TitleA.

can Someone help me?

Edit: Waylan Told me to do this and it doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func nextTapped(_ sender: Any) {



  let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

   databaseRef.child("ServiceA/Title")

    databaseRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in

       if error != nil {
           print("Error: \(error!)")
       } else {
           guard let data = snapshot?.documents else { return }
           LabelTest.text = data["TitleA"] as? String
       }
    }
}
```

it still doesn't work

Comment: You'll need to read the value from the database using its API. I recommend starting here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Comment: can you give me the code, i don't really understand

Comment: your going about this totally wrong. read the docs like Frank said, or look at youtube.      not only are you trying to reference from firestore, you'd need retrieve it as a dictionary  and create a class as a model for the data and place them into an array.

Comment: @jbiser361 The Firestore code actually came from someone who tried to help earlier. :-/ But aside from that, agreed that this is too broad and Stack Overflow isn't a replacement for the product documentation or other resources.

Comment: To clarify... that code doesn't work because part of it is for the Real Time Data Base (.child) and then part of it is Firestore (getDocuments). Those are two different API's.